# Portable way to set PATH environment variable?

Tags: python, path

I have been having issues with a python script that sets PATH environment variable. The script was written to be run from a 'native' windows python, but due to some mistake from my part, i ran it from a 'cygwin' windows python. So i was setting in my script the PATH environment variable with paths separated by ";", when the cygwin python needs ":" separated paths to understand it.

I'd like to make the script run in both python in the future. So, would there be a method, 'equivalent' of os.path.join(), that would concatenate paths with the correct delimiter depending on how the python version understands the PATH variable (and that possibly would use an equivalent of cygpath command to convert path formats if needed)

Comment: Why do you need to set `${PATH}`?

Comment: Because i run some unit tests from my python script, and i need to set a precise environment, for example to be sure that some precise DLLs are loaded, independently of the value of the environment variables before my python script was loaded

Comment: A test (however useful) that relies on "a precise environment", is very unlikely to be a "unit test". You should be able isolate the system under test from the DLLs and test it without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct, [`os.pathsep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.pathsep) is what you need:

```
import os
os.pathsep.join(['dir1', 'dir2'])
```

Will result in `dir1:dir2` in Unix and Cygwin and `dir1;dir2` in Windows

Comment: Seems like what i am looking for! But in the doc, it looks more like a constant, and not a class that would have a join() method. Are you sure about that syntax?

Comment: @bartoli that's just a string, and as such it definitely has the method `join()`.